# `this` is undefined inside anonymous function inside class method

Tags: javascript

consider the following snippet of code:

```js
function Animal() {

}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
    (function() {
        console.log(this);
    })();
}

var g = new Animal();
g.run();
```

It logs `Window` and this makes sense, but in the following piece, it outputs `undefined`!!!:

```js
class Animal {
    run() {

        (function() {
            console.log(this);
        })();

    }
}

var g = new Animal();
g.run();
```

This is the same code but using class syntax, what is different in class syntax that made `this` equal `undefined`?

Comment: and what did you expected?

Comment: I expected `Window` just like the prototype example, but I guess that was due to `strict mode`

Comment: All code in a class construct is interpreted in strict mode. If you would also set strict mode for the first script, you'd have the same output: `undefined`.